# VBA Dictionary - fetch records by keys and and write to a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have created a dictionary from the table below.
My question is how to retrieve records from the dictionary for specific keys (the one from H2:H6 for example) and write them on the sheet.
Any help or direction is highly appreciated in advance.

[image: Data table on Shet1]

```
    Sub CheckID()

    ' Declare and Create the Dictionary
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    ' Get the worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Get the range of all the adjacent data using CurrentRegion
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim objectID As clsDetector, i As Long, ID As Long
    'read through the data
    
    For i = 2 To rg.Rows.Count
    
        ID = rg.Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        ' Create a new clsDetector object
        Set objectID = New clsDetector
        
        ' Add the new clsDetector object to the dictionary
        dict.Add ID, objectID
        
        ' Set the values
        objectID.Name = rg.Cells(i, 2).Value
        objectID.DetectorType = rg.Cells(i, 3).Value
        objectID.DetectorValue = rg.Cells(i, 4).Value
                 
    Next i
        
    ' Write the Dictionary contents to the Immediate Window(Ctrl + G)
    
    Dim IDnumber As Variant
    ' Read through the dictionary
    For Each IDnumber In dict.Keys
    
        Set objectID = dict(IDnumber)
        With objectID
            ' Write to the Immediate Window (Ctrl + G)
            Debug.Print IDnumber, .Name, .DetectorValue, .DetectorValue
            
        End With   
    Next IDnumber         
End Sub
```

I'm using a Class named clsDetector in order to assign more properties to a key.

```
Option Explicit
' cls Detector Class Module Code
Public Name As Variant
Public DetectorType As Variant
Public DetectorValue As Variant
```

Comment: This looks like something you can do with `VLOOKUP` function, must you use VBA?

Comment: I have done it with VLookup, but takes way too long. About 10 or 15 seconds to populate 60 rows from 800 rows table.

Comment: Perhaps you can consider using `MATCH` on a hidden column to get the row number of the matched value then use INDEX to get the data from the hidden column, that way you dont have to do 2x extra matches to get the rest of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
    ' write to sheet
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In sh.Range("H2:H6")
        ID = cell.Value
        If dict.Exists(ID) Then
            Set objectID = dict(ID)
            With objectID
                cell.Offset(0, 1) = .Name
            End With
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was  looking for.